# CanJS - Control Communication

Tags: model-view-controller, canjs, canjs-control

I am learning CanJS now , so I want to try a very basic small demo. The demo is you will have different types of mobile recharge plans which displayed on the top (Radio buttons) and by choosing each plan the corresponding price options will be displayed in a table at the bottom.

For this demo I create two Model , 2 Control and 2 Template files , my question is how can two control communicate with each other? What is the standard way?

For now I am directly calling the control method through its instance , but I am not sure if it is right way to do. Also please explain Can.Route.

**Output**
http://jsfiddle.net/sabhab1/2mxfT/10/

**Data**

```
var CATEGORIES = [{id: 1 , name: "2G Internet Recharge"},
                  {id: 2 , name: "3G Internet Recharge"},
                  {id: 3 , name: "full talktime Recharge"},
                  {id: 4 , name: "Validity and talktime Recharge"},
                  {id: 5 , name: "National and international roaming"}];
var RECHARGEAMOUNTS =[{
                       id: 1 , 
                       values : [{amount: "Rs. 100" , benefit:"300 MB" ,validity:"30"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 200" , benefit:"1 GB" ,validity:"30"}]
                       },
                       {
                       id: 2 , 
                       values : [{amount: "Rs. 10" , benefit:"300 MB" ,validity:"30"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 99" , benefit:"100 GB" ,validity:"90"}]
                       },
                       {
                       id: 3 , 
                       values : [{amount: "Rs. 80" , benefit:"1 GB" ,validity:"50"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 99" , benefit:"100 GB" ,validity:"50"}]
                       },
                       {
                       id: 4 , 
                       values : [{amount: "Rs. 55" , benefit:"30 MB" ,validity:"10"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 200" , benefit:"1 GB" ,validity:"30"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 99" , benefit:"100 GB" ,validity:"90"}]
                       },
                       {
                       id: 5 , 
                       values : [{amount: "Rs. 880" , benefit:"100 MB" ,validity:"90"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 550" , benefit:"2 GB" ,validity:"30"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 1000" , benefit:"4 GB" ,validity:"90"},
                                 {amount: "Rs. 1550" , benefit:"10 GB" ,validity:"90"}]
                       }
                     ];
```

**Model**

```
//Model Category
CategoryModel = can.Model({
  findAll : function(){
      return $.Deferred().resolve(CATEGORIES);
    }
},{});

//Model Category
ReachargeAmountModel = can.Model({
    findAll : function(){
      return $.Deferred().resolve(RECHARGEAMOUNTS);
    },
    findOne : function(params){
      return $.Deferred().resolve(RECHARGEAMOUNTS[(+params.id)-1]);
    }
},{});
```

**Control**

```
**// Can Control 
var CategoryControl = can.Control({
    // called when a new Todos() is created
    init: function (element, options) {
        // get all todos and render them with
        // a template in the element's html
        var el = this.element;
        CategoryModel.findAll({}, function (values) {
            el.html(can.view('categoriesEJS', values))
        });
        this.options.rchAmtCtrl = new RechargeAmountControl("#rechnageAmountView"); 
    },
    'input click' : function( el, ev ) {
        var id = el.data('category').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        this.options.rchAmtCtrl.update(id);
    }

});
// Can Control 
var RechargeAmountControl = can.Control({
    // called when a new Todos() is created
    init: function (element, options) {
        // get all todos and render them with
        // a template in the element's html
        this.update(1);//this.update(id,this.element);
    },
    update : function(id){
        var el = this.element;
        ReachargeAmountModel.findOne({id: id}, function( rechargeAmount ){
            // print out the todo name
            //console.log(rechargeAmount.values[id].attr('benefit'));
            el.html(can.view('RechnageAmountEJS', rechargeAmount.values));
        });
    }
});**
```

**View**

```
<form id='categoriesView'></form>
</p>
<table id='rechnageAmountView'></table>
<script type='text/ejs' id='RechnageAmountEJS'>
    <tr>
        <th>Recharge Amount</th>
        <th>Benefits</th>
        <th>Validity(Days)</th>
    </tr>
    <% this.each(function( rechargeAmount ) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= rechargeAmount.attr( 'amount' ) %>
            </td>   
            <td>
                <%= rechargeAmount.attr( 'benefit' ) %>
            </td>   
            <td>
                <%= rechargeAmount.attr( 'validity' ) %>
            </td> 
        </tr>   
    <% }) %>

 </script>

<script type='text/ejs' id='categoriesEJS'>
    <% this.each(function( category ) { %>
        <input type="radio" 
            name="category" 
            <%= category.attr('id') == 1 ? 'checked' : '' %>
            value=<%= category.attr( 'name' ) %> 
            <%= (el) -> el.data('category',category) %>>
                <%= category.attr( 'name' ) %>
        </input>    
    <% }) %>
</script>
```

**Main Call**

```
new CategoryControl("#categoriesView");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways for doing this.

### 1. Calling methods directly

This is what you are doing and isn't necessarily wrong. To make things a little more flexible you could pass the class or instance of `RechargeAmountControl` when initializing `CategoryControl` instead of using it directly.

### 2. DOM events

Here it goes a little more into event oriented architecture. If you generally want to notify other Controls you can just trigger any kind of event and make them listen to it. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2mxfT/11/

```
' rechargeAmountUpdated': function(element, event, id){
    var el = this.element;
    console.log(arguments);
    ReachargeAmountModel.findOne({id: id}, function( rechargeAmount ){
        // print out the todo name
        //console.log(rechargeAmount.values[id].attr('benefit'));
        el.html(can.view('RechnageAmountEJS', rechargeAmount.values));
    });
}
```

### 3. Observables

Another option is to use Observables to maintain shared state. This is a great way to focus on the data and let live binding do all the rest. To make things more flexible, the state object should be passed during Control initialization (see http://jsfiddle.net/2mxfT/12/):

```
var state = new can.Observe();

new RechargeAmountControl("#rechnageAmountView", {
    state: state
}); 
new CategoryControl("#categoriesView", {
    state: state
});

state.attr('rechargeId', 1);
```

And then you can just listen to attribute changes in the RechargeAmountControl like this:

```
'{state} rechargeId': function(Construct, event, id){}
```

This handler will be called whenever you update your state Observe.

And this is also where `can.route` comes in. Basically can.route is an Observe that saves its state in the location hash. In the above example like `#!&rechargeId=1` (unless you initialize a specific route like `can.route(':rechargeId')`). If the location hash changes the Observe will be updated and vice versa.

Comment: You are awesome , I will go with option 3.May I ask you one last question , what is the real use of Can.Route?I just migrated to JS frameworks from Adobe Flex. Also is there any tutorial on CanJS apart from what website is provided , paid one is also fine.

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically can.route is just an Observe that persists its state to the window location hash.

Comment: Many Thanks Daff! Now its time for me learn Model List. Thanks Again.